# How I can use tag-list box html in shinyalert?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyalert

I use shinyalert and I want to put inside tag-list box when I use HTML, but it doesn't work

```
shinyalert(
      type = "info",
      confirmButtonText = "close",
      confirmButtonCol = "#6DBADE",
      size = "l", 
      closeOnEsc = TRUE,
      closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
      animation = TRUE,
      html = TRUE,
      text =  HTML("
             <form action=''>
             <input list='cars'>
             <datalist id='cars'>
             <option value='BMW' />
             <option value='Bentley' />
             </datalist>
             </form>") 
    )
```

any idea where is my problem?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean exactly in this case? Do you get an error message? Where exactly are you putting this code?

Comment: I've some button and when I click on the button it's open:   observeEvent(input[["btn"]]. I'ts all works (I get the pop-up window, title), but I dont get the textbox

Comment: It will be good if you could provide a fully reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, remove `HTML`.

Now, I don't know why, but the css `.sweet-alert input` has the property `display: none;`.

So you can do: `<input list='cars' style='display: block;'/>`.

---

## EDIT

However, the dropdown does not work. You can do this instead:

```
  shinyalert(
    type = "info",
    confirmButtonText = "close",
    confirmButtonCol = "#6DBADE",
    size = "l", 
    closeOnEsc = TRUE,
    closeOnClickOutside = TRUE,
    animation = TRUE,
    html = TRUE,
    text = selectInput("slct", label = NULL, choices = c("BMW", "Honda"))
  )
```